# Public Read-Only array data Member - Update outside of class Constructor

Tags: c#, arrays, readonly

Could someone please advise me if this is possible. I am looking at a code sample from Microsoft on GameState for their XNA framework. In one of the classes they use 'Public ReadOnly' array data members. Although not a practice that promotes OO but nothing wrong with that.

The class later instantiates it inside the constructor, so far so good, its documented on MSDN too.

PROBLEM: The class later iterates through the array in a class method and changes the data in the array. I looked on MSDN and Googled on it and everywhere I look it says flat out that will error out. Is there a special exception for read-only arrays?

Please advise.

```
public class InputState
{
    public readonly KeyboardState[] CurrentKeyboardStates;
    public readonly KeyboardState[] LastKeyboardStates;

    public InputState()
    {
        CurrentKeyboardStates = new KeyboardState[max];  
        LastKeyboardStates = new KeyboardState[max];  
    }
    //Does not make sense code...
    public void Update()
    {
        for (int i=0; i < max; ++i)
        {
            //this should throw errors...
            CurrentKeyboardStates[i] = LastKeyboardStates[i];  
            LastKeyboardStates[i] = Keyboard.GetState();
            //more code....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182299.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing elements of a read-only array is perfectly fine, you just cannot re-assign the reference. (cannot set CurrentKeyboardStates/LastKeyboardStates to a new array, etc.) The element values can be changed.

Comment: Thank you, I get it. The array is read-only, meaning cannot reassign the array, but the elements can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

`readonly` means that  the **variable** cannot be changed, after it is set in the constructor.  However, in this case, that is a reference to an array object, which *can* be changed.

If the field is a value type (for example `int`), then your understanding holds true. The field can be set by an initializer, or by any constructor. It's pretty much the same thing as a `const` field.

But if it is a reference, then all we can guarantee is that it will always refer to the *same object*. Whether or not you can modify that object is up to its implementation. So in the case of an array, you can change the contents of the array, but not its length, for example.

See the MSDN documentation for [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx).

[SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) points out this Warning that will be generated from Code Analysis: [CA2105: Array fields should not be read only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182299.aspx). It is for the very purpose that you bring up here. Marking the array `readonly` gives you a false sense of security that it cannot be modified. However, the only thing you *can't* do is assign a different array to that field.

---

If you want to expose an array of information to the outside, without the possibility of it being changed, the best way to do so is an `IEnumerable<T>` property:

```
public class Foo {
    private int[] _data = new int[40];

    public IEnumerable<int> Data {
        get { return _data; }
    }
}
```

This will allow a consumer of that class to iterate over it, just like any other `IEnumerable`:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
foreach (int d in f.Data) {
    //...
}

f.Data[0] = 7;           // This won't work. IEnumerable doesn't have [] operator.
f.Data = new int[10];    // This won't work. Data only has a getter.
```

Comment: Ok, I get it. cannot change/reassign the array, but its elements are accessible to be changed. FYI - I did look at the example that you linked in your reply. It only shows a single value not an array, that was the very reason I asked for help. Thanks again, not trying to sound ungrateful.

Comment: You've got it. Does this work for your solution, or does it **need** to be actually read-only, like you expected?

Comment: Right - don't worry, I **fully** understand the inadequacies of the MSDN docs :-)  I think I actually saw one instance where something on MSDN linked to SO.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response. This is not my code, just a sample project from Microsoft that I going through. I personally would not expose data members directly, but through Properties. For arrays I would return a clone so my internal states cannot be messed up by the false security of the read-only key word.

Comment: It is much more efficient to return an `IEnumerable`, than a copy of the array. I've added information to show as such.

Comment: Thank you sir. Appreciate the IEnumerator sample. You have saved me some time looking for a sample on how to implement an IEnumerator. I'm coming from a C++ college CS background, but as I'm learning C#, starting to like C# more.

Comment: That's not going to solve the problem actually. A consumer of the class can still cast the property to an array and be able to modify the contents. Like I said in my answer you need to implement something for this yourself using the interfaces.

Comment: @Mithon I suppose that is true, if they knew it was actually an array, right? Or, one could just use reflection and modify anything, anywhere. How much do we have to babysit consumers of our APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Like the other two posters mentions, there's nothing wrong with changing the item that is being referenced. You just can't change the reference itself when it's readonly.

So what you want is not an array, which is modifiable, but some other structure that isn't modifiable once defined. I'm not gonna give you a complete solution, but you should check out the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` interfaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx.

Comment: @badboy11 You're moving the accepted answer around from one question to the next. (Seen it on each of the 3 answers.) You can only have 1 accepted answers, but you can upvote many. So pick the one you think helped you the most. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I was confused about the voting. All answers were good so was having a difficult time selecting the one that I felt was the most clear and concise not only for me but anyone else that came across this post in future.